# Report displays correctly in report designer, but displays no data when presented through the web viewer

Tags: crystal-reports

My report is written in Crystal Reports for VS 2010 using c#.net. Its using the CR web viewer.

It displays everything correctly in VS and whilst testing it on IIS7 (locally) using the web viewer.

When I print or export the report (from the web viewer) all the 'fixed' fields (labels, text fields, images etc.) are printed but all the 'data' fields are not printed, just blank.

Have I missed a setting somewhere that allows the data in the report to persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the reportdocument wasn't being saved to the session and restored correctly on a postback event. Modified a few bits and pieces and now its working like a charm.

Comment: Cool, thanks for posting. To clarify, am I correct here: (1) you're generating the report on a web server and (2) when you write "exporting" you're talking about some feature of the web viewer, not the Export feature in Report Designer.

Comment: in short (1) yes and (2) yes. The web viewer export option is the one i was refering to (but it works the same as the print functionality ie. requires the session saving to create its output)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might need to select **Save Data with Report**, which is on the File menu in Report Designer.

Comment: I have just tried enabling 'save data with report' from within the report preview in VS2010. Sadly this hasn't fixed the problem. any other ideas?